# Return value from list according to index number

Tags: python, pandas

I have been struggling to find the pandas solution to this without looping:

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [[6,1,1,1], [1,5,1,1], [1,1,11,1], [1,1,1,20]]})

                A
0   [6, 1, 1, 1]
1   [1, 5, 1, 1]
2   [1, 1, 11, 1]
3   [1, 1, 1, 20]
```

output:

```
                A   B
0   [6, 1, 1, 1]    6
1   [1, 5, 1, 1]    5
2   [1, 1, 11, 1]   11
3   [1, 1, 1, 20]   20
```

I have tried so many different things over the past hour or so, and I know the solution will be an embarrassingly simple one-liner. Thanks for your help -- not my python day today!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a simple list comprehension:

```
df['B'] = [s[i] for i, s in zip(df.index, df['A'])]
```

Or if you want only diagonal values:

```
df['B'] = np.diagonal([*df['A']])
```

---

```
               A   B
0   [6, 1, 1, 1]   6
1   [1, 5, 1, 1]   5
2  [1, 1, 11, 1]  11
3  [1, 1, 1, 20]  20
```

Comment: Thank you, I was getting close on my list comprehension but was not prevailing. I absolutely love the solution for `np.diagonal`. So simple.

Comment: what does the `*` do? I see that the results are different, but was curious how it works.

Comment: Thanks David! `[*df['A']]` is used here to `unpack` the column `A` which is equivalent to using `df['A'].tolist()`

Answer (score 2):

Solution using numpy:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [[6,1,1,1], [1,5,1,1], [1,1,11,1], [1,1,1,20]]})
df['B'] = pd.Series(np.diag(np.vstack(df['A'].to_numpy())), index=df.index)

df
```

Comment: Thanks! Need to get more familiar with some of the numpy functionality outside of the core numpy functions like `np.where`, etc. For example, I've never used `diag` or `vstack` before, so I am trying to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

I have also been able to solve my own question, but terribly. I will post the solution anyway:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [[6,1,1,1], [1,5,1,1], [1,1,11,1], [1,1,1,20]]})
s = df.explode('A')
i = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df['B'] = s.loc[s.index == i, 'A']

               A   B
0   [6, 1, 1, 1]   6
1   [1, 5, 1, 1]   5
2  [1, 1, 11, 1]  11
3  [1, 1, 1, 20]  20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply() and the dataframe index (row.name) to extract the diagonal elements.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [[6,1,1,1], [1,5,1,1], [1,1,11,1], [1,1,1,20]]})

df['B']=df.apply(lambda row: row['A'][row.name],axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output :

```
    A              B
0   [6, 1, 1, 1]   6
1   [1, 5, 1, 1]   5
2  [1, 1, 11, 1]  11
3  [1, 1, 1, 20]  20
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying a `.name` implementation as well. However, in my actual dataframe, I was doing so after a long list comprehension, and it wasn't working. When I split into two lines of code, it worked with the code you posted.